# Remote Control Home PC from Corporate Work PC

Tags: windows, linux, android, synergy, remote-control

Here is my situation: I am currently on a Windows XP workstation at work.  I have an android tablet that I use to splashtop into my home PC.  I would like to be able to use my work keyboard and mouse to control my home PC while I am splashtop'd into it using my tablet.

My work PC is on a corporate LAN, and not on the same network as my tablet.  The company I work for provides wifi for personal devices, but they are not accessable to the internal network.

I thought about going the Synergy route, however that would require my home PC to be able to connect to my work PC which isn't really possible.  The opposite would work though, if I could reverse connect the server to the client, but the Synergy software doesn't really support that.

I do have a couple linux boxes running at home, so I can ssh into my home network and tunnel ports via SSH if needed.

With what I have, how can I accomplish seamless keyboard and mouse sharing between my work PC and either my home PC or my android tablet?

Comment: I don't know if the corporate network structure would allow it, but you can find out in a few minutes.  What about installing a VNC server on your home machine, and then just using a browser to connect to your home IP at port 5800 (the browser based java client port)?  Of course, you'd have visual control as well but provided that you can connect on that port through the corporate connection, that should do just fine.  Plus, with VNC, you could also connect through your Tablet at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logmein](http://logmein.com) is free and provides a browser 'remote' functionality, just need to go to logmein.com and sign up then install the software on your home computer, and you can access it from the internet, or your tablet, and it's all graphical

> Users worldwide rely on LogMeIn solutions for remote control, file sharing, systems management, data backup, business collaboration and on-demand customer support of PCs, servers, Macintosh computers, smartphones and other connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/9-Does-it-work-behind-firewalls-proxy-server-and-NAT-routers.aspx)

> Does it work behind firewalls, proxy server and NAT routers? Yes! That
>   is what we made TeamViewer for. TeamViewer will allow you to share
>   your desktop over any kind of internet-/LAN-connection and over almost
>   any firewall.

It worked for me in the similar to your situation.